# A Property of the Ito Integral

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Let $f,g \in \mathcal{V}(0,T)$ and let $0 \leq S < T.$ Then

$E[\int^{T}_{S}f dB_t]=0$

Apparently this holds clearly for elementary functions, (Im not so sure), and can be obtained by taking limits. Intuitively to me this property does not seem true and I cannot see how to prove it exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is in two steps:

- it is true for elementary functions: you just have to prove that for every
  $Y_i$ measurable with respect to $F_{t_{i-1}}$,
  $$
  E\left[\sum_{i=0}^{N-1} Y_i (B_{t_i} - B_{t_{i-1}})\right] =0
  $$(it is quite easy).
- then, write an element $f$ as an $L^2$ limit of such elementary processes $f_n$.
  Then, $$
  E \left[\int_S^T f_n dB - \int_S^T f dB 
  \right]^2
  = E\int_S^T |f_n - f|^2 ds\to 0
  $$
  via Ito's isometry.

Comment: To prove property 1, do you use $Y_i$ is measurable w.r.t $F_{t_{i-1}}$, hence independent of $B_{t_{i}}-B_{t_{i-1}}$ (since $B_{t_{i}}-B_{t_{i-1}}$ is independent of $B_t, \forall t\le t_{i-1}$ and then prove by definition)?